# Org-mode emphasis markers: surround symbol

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have this text, where `|` is point.

`This is the te|xt.`

Now I want to put the word `text` in bold, so I use Org keybindings and do `C-c C-x C-f` and pick `*`. This is what happens:

`This is the te *|* xt.`

Would it be possible to have the markers surround the symbol where point is? Like this:

`This is the *text*|.`

I know `org-emphasize` works on the active region, but it would be quicker if it was done automatically on the symbol where point is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a function that marks the current word when the region isn't already active:

```
(defun org-emphasize-dwim (&optional char)
  (interactive)
  (unless (region-active-p)
    (backward-word)
    (mark-word))
  (org-emphasize char))
```

You can rebind the keys to call this instead of the normal `org-emphasize`:

```
(define-key org-mode-map [remap org-emphasize] #'org-emphasize-dwim)
```

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this:

```
(defun bold-region-or-point ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (progn
        (goto-char (region-end))
        (insert "*")
        (goto-char (region-beginning))
        (insert "*"))
    (insert "**")
    (backward-char)))
```

and bind it to a convenient key like:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "s-b") 'bold-region-or-point)
```

Comment: Could this solution be modified so it could apply the *s on the beginning and end of lines in that active region as well?